# Can I use Proxifier and Fiddler together?

Tags: http, tcp, proxy, fiddler, wireshark

I am trying to fake a server response by using Fiddler. I have a program that wants to verify activation information, and when it sends a request to the server for authentication, it is not detected by Fiddler(however, it is detected with Wireshark, the program uses TCP). Fiddler only filters http traffic, and Wireshark does not have any breakpoints or the ability to edit packets. So I downloaded Proxifier to force the application to use a http protocol and direct my traffic, however, I cannot get it to direct it to another application such as Fiddler.

My question is, can I use Proxifier to route all traffix to Fiddler so that I may intercept the activation request by the program? In other words, can I set up a chain of proxies on the same computer? If so, how would I set that up?

The chain I would be interested in setting up is like this.

Applications-->Proxifier-->Fiddler-->Internet

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Is the traffic in question actually HTTP[S]? If not, Fiddler can't help you.

If so, you might find it simpler to use your `HOSTS` file to just point the target application at Localhost and use Fiddler without using Proxifier.

But using Proxifier should work just fine; just be sure to configure it to use `HTTP` rather than `SOCKS` as the target proxy.

Comment: I'm not sure. The program seems to be using 3 protocols, HTTP, TCP, and DNS. Here is what Wireshark shows me. 
http://imageshack.com/a/img607/793/ikqm.png

If I were to edit the HOSTS file, would that only redirect HTTP traffic or all kinds of traffic?

Proxifier cannot edit packets so I dont know what I can do with that.